# How To integrate this $I=\int \frac {3x^3+2x^{11}}{(2x^4+3x^2+1)^4}dx$

Tags: integration

How Can I solve this question?

$$I=\int \frac  {3x^3+2x^{11}}{(2x^4+3x^2+1)^4}dx$$

This question was aksed on my test.In the test i had to leave this question due to time shortage but even after returning home i am not be able to proceed to first step.

This question doesn't fit into any general or reducible form that i am aware of .Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

**Somebody, edited my question  wrong and missed the power 11 over x therefore i am correcting my question again.**

Comment: It is $$\frac{20160 x^{10}+75594 x^8+110037 x^6+77487 x^4+26397
   x^2+5040 \left(2 x^4+3 x^2+1\right)^3 \log \left(2
   x^2+1\right)+3493}{24 \left(2 x^4+3
   x^2+1\right)^3}-210 \log \left(x^2+1\right)+C$$

Comment: Was it really an indefinite integral or were there limits?  The integrand is an odd function, so if you integrate from, say $-2$ to $2$, the answer is $0.$   It seems to me like it's that sort of question.

Comment: Are all the variables $x$'s or are some of them $u$'s?  Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) whenever possible.  Images can't be browsed and aren't accessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: is it $2x^2$ or $2x$ at the numerator ? Can't read it .

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t:=x^2$ so$$I=\int\frac{\frac32t+1}{(t+1)^4(2t+1)^4}dt.$$Now integrate the integrand's [partial fraction decomposition](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%283t%2F2%2B1%29%2F%28%28t%2B1%29%5E4%282t%2B1%29%5E4%29+as+partial+fractions).

Comment: $$\dfrac{3t}2+1=a(t+1)+b(2t+1)$$ Find $a,b$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That works, but to integrate $\frac{1}{(t+1)^n(2t+1)^{7-n}}$ for $n\in\{3,\,4\}$ takes some decomposition anyway.